# Extract SCORM Quiz Questions

Tags: scorm

I'm looking to extract the Quiz data(Questions) from a quiz and need the data out of the SCORM container. How can i get that....Please help me n this case..

regards

Arun Krishnan G

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends where the questions are stored.

Sometimes content is stored in an xml or js file (as json) or even a txt file outside of the content player (usually a swf). In that case you just extract the scorm .zip and find the right content file.

Sometimes the content is compiled inside a swf content player. So if you check all those other files inside the scorm zip listed above and none of them has the content you need, you'll have to use a swf decompiler like Trillix to access the actionscript inside the swf.

Comment: Thanks,....i am not able to find out the exact file ...do u have any idea about that...if u have any idea please  share it with me....waiting for ur reply...

Comment: I would need to see the actual package. Can you provide a link?